# Angular - Callback function after <select> <options> is updated from API

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a `<select>` element in a form with the list of categories, I need to fetch the list of categories from API.

Here is my type script file.

```
export class ExtranetRegisterComponent implements OnInit {

    form = null;
  categories = [];

  constructor(private router: Router, private _fb: FormBuilder, private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.buildForm();
    var categories = this.httpClient.get('http://api.local/api/v1/categories');
    categories.subscribe(
      (data: any[]) => {
        this.categories = data;
        // Apply this code when categories gets updated in the template (DOM)
        $('select').selectric('refresh');
      }
    )
  }

  buildForm() {
    this.form = this._fb.group({
      category: ['',[]],
      subcategory: ['',[]],
      business_name: ['',[]]
    });
    this.onChanges();
  }

  onChanges(): void {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      alert('hi there');
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.selectric').selectric();
    });

  }

  onSubmit() {
    return false;
  }

}
```

Here is the related template file.

```
<form [formGroup]="form" name="form" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <select id="category" formControlName="category" class="selectric form-control">
                <option>Select Provider Type</option>
                <option value="{{category.id}}" *ngFor="let category of categories">{{category.name['en']}}</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 form-group">
            <select id="subcategory" formControlName="subcategory" class="selectric form-control">
                <option>Select Category</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 form-group">
            <input class="form-control modify-block-input your-detail-input" placeholder="Business Name">
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-default center-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

It is successfully fetching data from the API call, however, what I need is when the  elements gets updated in the DOM, I want a callback function to be invoked, this is because I need to refresh the plugin.

Thank you.

Comment: when the async call comes back, that's when you should invoke your callback function. With that said, the callback function should be placed after the line of code this.categories = data;

Comment: Tried and it is not working, perhaps because the dom is not updated yet at this point. I wanted to call it after the dom is updated.

Comment: I got it to work using MutationObserver where I listen to dom change event and refresh the jquery plugin accordingly. However I wonder if Angular has any event listener on dom update for form control. What I get to know is formcontrol do have value change observable, however I am looking for dom change observable instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using MutationObserver (more information here [Detect changes in the DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom))

The other alternative I am trying is using a callback for `ngFor`